# CUT LINES OF FLAT FILE

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

I have a flat file without Carriage Return and Line Feed,to delimit the line break.

For example my file "file.t4"

```
Sergio 180 32 1988  Juan 148 34    1986 Silvia 162 30 1900
```

I need a file "filev2.t4" that is cut every **20** characters and the result will be this:

```
Sergio 180 32 1988
Juan 148 34 1986
Silvia 162 30 1900
```

I try to do it in bash with "cut" command but I don't get the wanted result

Could you help me?

Comment: Good that you have mentioned that you have tried few things with `cut`, you could mention them in your question; there is nothing right or wrong as we all are here to learn, cheers.

Comment: `awk '$1=$1' FPAT='.{1,20}' OFS='\n' file.t4 >filev2.t4`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can also be achieved using `fold` (like `cut`, a part of coreutils)

Breaks lines every 20 characters:

```
fold -b -w 20 file
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` it will be an easy task, please try following. Written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '{gsub(/.{20}/,"&\n")} 1' Input_file
```

Same logic with `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.{20}/&\n/g' Input_file
```

with a more portable alternative being

```
sed 's/.\{20\}/&\
/g' Input_file
```

according to the [POSIX specification, `s` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03).

Comment: Nice answer, Ravinder, I have edited with a more portable alternative instead of commenting because I don't think I can put a literal newline in code in a comment. Feel free to rollback if you find it too intrusive. Cheers!

Comment: @Quasímodo, thank you for adding informative info, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Pure `bash` approach:

```sh
(while IFS= read -r -n20 line; do
   printf "%s\n" "$line"
 done < file.t4
 [[ -n $line ]] && printf "%s\n" "$line") > filev2.t4
```

results in the new file being

```
Sergio 180 32 1988
Juan 148 34    1986
Silvia 162 30 1900
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution

```
$ perl -ne 'while(/.{20}/osmg) { print "$&\n" } ' sergio.txt
Sergio 180 32 1988
Juan 148 34    1986
Silvia 162 30 1900
$
```